# How can I show a route map in mail

Tags: php, google-maps

How can I show a route map in mail. I'm using google map. When I used the static map, it is showing the route by a straight line. I need to show the route path like in the directions in google map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to setup the directions first in google maps. Then you can details under after doing the route search. There will be a share icon there.

You then can get embed code like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m28!1m12!1m3!1d3029.057209420699!2d-111.79932313511478!3d40.60656140199723!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m13!3e6!4m5!1s0x8752632fdfe0b545%3A0xc221aa516234ef7b!2s7993+East+Norwood+Road%2C+Cottonwood+Heights%2C+UT!3m2!1d40.60591!2d-111.797326!4m5!1s0x875263255afdd113%3A0x82922877960a0ecf!2s7883+Chadbourne+Dr%2C+Cottonwood+Heights%2C+UT+84121!3m2!1d40.607576099999996!2d-111.79829769999999!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1451286018803" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

embed that in your email.